# Access function in a child with Flash CC and Createjs

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, flash-cc

Hi all I have a problem with my program on flash cc with createjs. I have a movie clip with instances name "target1". Inside it, I have a function called `triggerTarget()`, but when I'm trying to accessing this function on movieclip "target1", it always showing `TypeError:target1.triggerTarget is not a function`. Here is my code :

```
var that=this;
that['target1'].triggerTarget();
```

I'm also trying this code.

```
exportRoot['target1'].triggerTarget();
```

I can access that movieclip object, but I can not reach the function inside it, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a typo here? I don't know [tag:flash-cc], but I would expect the function to be `triggerTarget`, with two Gs in trigger…

Comment: Thank you very much for your respon Owen,  I've trying any other names and get the same error. The function inside the movieclip is a custom function and I want to access it. I can get the movieclip object properties like `x`, `y` or `alpha`, but still can't reach the custom function I've made.

Comment: Ah. In that case I don't know; sorry. I hope you find your answer soon :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put code on the timeline, and do not properly scope it, it will not work as expected (especially if you come from an ActionScript background).

For example, this does *not* work:

```
function triggerTarget() {
    gotoAndPlay("frame");
}
```

But this should:

```
this.triggerTarget = function() {
    this.gotoAndPlay("frame");
}
```

In the second example, the function exists as part of the object, so you can call it on that object. The first sample defines it in it's scope, but it is basically anonymous, and there is no way to access it.

Unfortunately, this is a reality with JavaScript. There is no implicit scoping of timeline code, so you have to be aware of how things are defined.

Comment: Wow it works like I expected ^_^. Thanks for the solution (and the explanation too) Lanny, I really appreciated it.